# Fabrication::MisplacedFabricateError while using Fabrication Gem on Rails 2.3.16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, activerecord, fabrication-gem

I am using Fabrication gem v-2.5.0 on Rails 2.3.16 but get the following errors when I run the unit test cases:

Below is the code snippet :

> **First case**

```
Fabricate(:some_modal) 
Fabrication::MisplacedFabricateError: # from /Users/user_xyz/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-        2011.03@project/gems/fabrication-2.5.0/lib/fabrication.rb:51:in `Fabricate' from (irb):3
```

> **Second case**

```
Fabricate(:some_other_modal)
SyntaxError: /Users/user_xyz/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@project/gems/fabrication-2.5.0/lib/fabrication/generator/active_record.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' ...ttributes, without_protection: true)
```

Can someone please help me resolve these.

> **Modal Class :**

```
  class ErrorCode
      attr_accessor :mappings
      has_many :error_code_mappings
  end
```

> **Fabricator :**

```
Fabricator(:error_code) do
  application_id 77
  error_code_mappings(:count => 3) { |error_code, i| Fabricate.build(:error_code_mapping,      :error_code => Fabricate.build(:error_code, :code => error_code.code + i))}
end
```

> **Unit test file:**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ErrorCodeTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  context "ErrorCode" do
    setup do
      @error_code = Fabricate.build(:error_code)
      assert(@error_code.valid?)
    end
   should "have setter for mapping attribute" do
      assert_respond_to(@error_code, :mappings=)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fabrication** requires `Ruby 1.9` and higer version. And the current version of ruby that is being used as per the given code snippets is `REE 1.8.7.`

Upgrade your ruby version & then u can get it working!